# Doing automatically generated admin interface and content management in Pyramid

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

Do Python Pyramid have an Admin Interface like other CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla?

I mean a admin interface from where all the website settings can be managed like menu settings, pages, content etc.

If yes can you please let me know how can I access it.

If no can you please let me know how to add a admin interface to it with an authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Pyramid is not a CMS.  Development framework.  Downvoting.

Comment: Websauna is admin interface for Pyramid http://websauna.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid is a web framework and does not provide any web application out of the box. You can write an admin interface or any other kind of web application on top of Pyramid. There are many open source packages that provide an admin interface, including WebSauna, Kotti, and SubstanceD. For a list of such packages and other packages for extending Pyramid, visit https://trypyramid.com/resources-extending-pyramid.html and filter packages.

Answer (score 1):

Websauna is admin interface for Pyramid http://websauna.org/ - how to use it please refer to tutorial http://websauna.org/docs/tutorials/gettingstarted/index.html However you still need to write your own content types as Websauna does not provide those for you.

For content management system with stock content types, your Pyramid options are

- Kotti http://kotti.pylonsproject.org/ (PostgreSQL, actively developed)
- SubstanceD http://www.substanced.net/ (ZODB)